# Pintle injector in a Vortex Cooled Chamber Wall (VCCW) Engine

Tags: rockets, engine-design, engines

All the articles I have found show the VCCW engines using flat plate injectors. With the inherent combustion stability of a Pintle injector system, it would seem to be a better choice, yet I find no evidence that it was tried.

Does anyone have any references on this?

Comment: I can't find a source for this, but I suppose the radial speed component induced on the propellants by the pintle injectors would disturb the cooling vortex.